# Log/track clicks on a page the right way - how?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm building minor a page monitoring tool, and I want to log clicks on a given page.

It's important that I later can query out clicks on a given day on a specific page etc. So far this is what I build, but I'm not sure if it's the best solution.

```
$clicks = Click::where('page_id', $pid)
            ->whereDate('created_at', DB::raw('CURDATE()'))
            ->get();

if($clicks->isEmpty()) {
    $clicks = new click;
    $clicks->clicks = 1;
    $clicks->page_id = $pid;
    $clicks->save();
}
else {
    $clicks->first()->increment('clicks');
}
```

And when I want to show it to the user I'll be doing as follow:

```
@foreach ($page->click as $click)
<?php
if(check_in_range($from, $to, $click->created_at->format('Y-m-d'))) {
    $clicks = $clicks + $click->clicks; 
}
?>
@endforeach
{{ $clicks }}
```

So basically everytime someone visits the page, I'll create a new row in the database, but if there already is a click for that day I'll increment it.

Another solution could be just logging each click as one row, but that would very quickly be a lot of rows.

I'm looking for suggestions and a better solution (if any) :)

Comment: While I don't have a direct answer to your question, there are a few things I would advice you to do. Laravel uses the MVC pattern, in this pattern the code you showed which sums your clicks should be either in the model or controller (probably model in this case).

Comment: I don't know what is the better solution. But maybe I must save every click as row saving page_id, user_id, created_at...etc. all information that maybe you can need. After that only a question `Click::where('page_id',$page_id')->whereDate('created_at',DB::raw('CURDATE()'))->get()->count()` to get the quantity of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are a lot of solutions. In this case maybe is convenient save all information about click in by row.

And only ask for the click in and specific day

```
$start_date = 'your date';
$end_date = 'your_date'; //Maybe you can give the choice to select a range of dates;
$clicks = Click::where('page_id',$page_id)->whereBetween('created_at',$start_date,$end_date)->get();
$qty = $clicks->count();
```